# How to perform paired t-test without whole sample data?

Tags: r, statistics, t-test

I have several data summaries for paired t-test from three difference sources (hospitals), which means I don't have the whole sample data.  What I've got to perform the paired t-test is the mean (difference of each paired sample data).
The data looks like the table below (each row is one patient) and I have the `mean(diff)` and `sd(diff)`.
Is there any function with which I could easily perform paired t-test and get the 95% CI?
There is just no way of getting the whole data set, due to patient privacy concerns.

```
3 months 6 months  diff
  1         3       -2
  2         1        1
  5         9       -4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paired t-test is exactly equivalent to a t-test that tests the mean of the differences against a null hypothesis of zero.

```
diffs <- c(-2,1,-4)
m <- mean(diffs)
s <- sd(diffs)
n <- length(diffs)
```

Now suppose you don't know `diffs`, just `m`, `s` and `n` (all three are necessary)

```
pval <- 2*pt(abs(m/s),lower.tail=FALSE,df=n)
## 0.555
qq <- qt(0.975,df=n)
ci <- m + c(-1,1)*qq*s
## [1] -9.675648  6.342314
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! But what if I do want to perform t-test assuming equal variance?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.  Equal variance of what?  Or do you mean *unequal* variance?  I can't see how an unequal-variance test even makes sense in the paired case ...

Comment: I'm sorry. Your question is about a paired t-test, that's what I answered. If you have another question, you should ask it as a separate post. Otherwise this risks becoming a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) ...

Comment: I mean, not for the paired-case. for two independents samples t-test. Great, thank you for letting me know :)

Comment: If this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept the answer ...